# Falha de segmentação - C

Tags: c, string, ponteiro, char, union

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int validaTipo(char t);

typedef union{
    struct contratoIndividual{
        unsigned int idContrato;
        char cpf[14]; 
        char nome[50]; //Nome completo
        int idade;
        float renda;
    }contI;

    struct contratoColetivo{
        unsigned int idContrato;
        char cnpj[18];
        char razaoSocial[30];
        int quantEmpregMasc;
        int quantEmpregFem;
        int quantDepen;
        float rendaMedia;
    }contC;
}uniao;

int main(void){

    uniao u;
    char tipo;

    printf("Tipo de Contrato: [I/C] ");
    scanf("%c", &tipo);

    printf("%c", tipo);

    if (validaTipo(tipo)){
        printf("Certinho!");
    }
    else{
        printf("Erradnho");
    }

    return 1;
}

int validaTipo(char t){
    char tipos[3] = {'I', 'i', 'C', 'c'};
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        if(!strcmp(tipos[i], t)){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por favor Haryel, coloque o código e não a imagem.

Comment: Seja mais descritivo na sua pergunta e problema. Só jogar um codigo de 50 linhas e dizer "Falha de segmentação" é demasiado vago.

Answer (score 2):

Haryel, o erro ocorre por conta de você utilizar a strcmp em um variável do tipo char, sendo que na verdade, ela compara uma cadeia de caracteres, ou seja, um array de char.

No seu caso, uma comparação de igualdade simples (==) já resolveria o seu problema:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int validaTipo(char t);

typedef union{
    struct contratoIndividual{
        unsigned int idContrato;
        char cpf[14]; 
        char nome[50]; //Nome completo
        int idade;
        float renda;
    }contI;

    struct contratoColetivo{
        unsigned int idContrato;
        char cnpj[18];
        char razaoSocial[30];
        int quantEmpregMasc;
        int quantEmpregFem;
        int quantDepen;
        float rendaMedia;
    }contC;
} uniao;

int main(void){

    uniao u;
    char tipo;

    printf("Tipo de Contrato: [I/C] ");
    scanf("%c", &tipo);

    printf("%c", tipo);

    if (validaTipo(tipo)){
        printf("Certinho!");
    }
    else{
        printf("Erradinho");
    }

    return 1;
}

int validaTipo(char t){
    char tipos[4] = {'I', 'i', 'C', 'c'};
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        if (tipos[i] == t) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A sua declaração do array tipos também estava incorreta, tendo apenas 3 posições, com isso o 'c' era considerado um erro.

---

Aqui um exemplo de uso da strcmp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    char nome[7] = "Daniel";
    char comp[7] = "Daniel";
    char erro[7] = "daniel";

    printf("\nResultado da strcmp 01: %d", strcmp(nome, comp));
    printf("\nResultado da strcmp 02: %d", strcmp(nome, erro));

    return 1;
}
```